# how to select column1 and column2 but distinct only column1

Tags: mysql, distinct

How can i both select column1(type) and column2(price) but distinct only column1(type)?

```
<?php
$query ="SELECT type , price FROM products ORDER BY type , price";
?>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a small amount of sample data along with the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT type, price
FROM products
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY type
```

This is not strictly legal SQL, because `GROUP BY` normally requires that all the non-grouped columns be aggregation functions, but MySQL allows it as an extension. It will select an arbitrary `price` from all the rows with the same `type`.

There's no point in putting `price` in the `ORDER BY` clause. The second ordering column is only used when there are rows with the same first column, but since we're making `type` distinct that can never happen.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT type , price FROM products GROUP BY type ORDER BY type , price
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^----this will select distinct type
```

[some docs about group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to `GROUP BY` column1 rather than use `DISTINCT`. You would also need to use an aggregate function on the price.

List of aggregates for MySql here: [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

e.g. To get all distinct types with an average price use:

```
SELECT type, AVG(price) FROM products GROUP BY type ORDER BY type
```

*If you don't NEED to aggregate the price in some way then you're probably best leaving it out as even if MySql will return something it isn't going to be a predictable value anyway*